# script mediator get from payload

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-micro-integrator

I used script mediator to make multi where condition ,i have a method get the script is correct when i get from query parama as below :

```
    <script language="js"><![CDATA[var queryString = "WHERE ";
var AND =" AND ";
var id = mc.getProperty('query.param.id');
var age = mc.getProperty('query.param.age');
var note = mc.getProperty('query.param.note');
queryString += (id)? " id=" + id+" " + AND : " ";
queryString += (age)? " age=" + age+" " + AND : " ";
queryString += (note)? " note=" + note+" " + AND : "";
queryString =queryString.toString();
var n = queryString.lastIndexOf(AND);
mc.setProperty('queryString',queryString.slice(0, n));]]></script>
            <property expression="get-property('queryString')" name="uri.var.queryString" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="http://ITMTNF3RRJSJ:8290/services/studenttest/readstudent?filtreQuery={uri.var.queryString}">
```

But now i have a method put with multi where i tried get from payload json then i used the iterate mediator to do the update according to the list of objects but it doesnt't work

here is my code:

```
 <resource methods="PUT" uri-template="modif">
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="json-eval($)" name="JSONPayload" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <script language="js"><![CDATA[var queryString = "WHERE ";
var AND =" AND ";
  var pl_string = mc.getProperty("JSONPayload");
                    var newPayload="{\"event\": " + pl_string + "}";
                   
queryString += (id)?  " id=" + id+" " + AND : " ";
queryString += (age)?" age=" + age+" " + AND : " ";
queryString += (note)? " note=" + note+" " + AND : "";
queryString =queryString.toString();
var n = queryString.lastIndexOf(AND);
 mc.setPayloadJSON(newPayload);]]></script>
            <property expression="get-property('queryString')" name="uri.var.queryString" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="get-property('JSONPayload')" name="msgg"/>
            </log>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="http://ITMTNF3RRJSJ:8290/services/studenttest/readstudent?filtreQuery={uri.var.queryString}">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <iterate expression="//etuidants/etudiant">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                            <format>{
  "_putmodifstudent": {
                 "id":${payload.etudiant.id},
                 "nom":"${payload.etudiant.nom}",
                 "prenom":"${payload.etudiant.prenom}",
                 "age":"${payload.etudiant.age}",
                 "note":"${payloadetudiant.note}",
                 }
}</format>
                            <args/>
                        </payloadFactory>
                        <call>
                            <endpoint>
                                <http method="put" statistics="enable" trace="enable" uri-template="http://ITMTNF3RRJSJ:8290/services/studenttest/modifstudent">
```